# Why ListActivity long click detection is so complex in Android?

Tags: android, listview, click, detection

In my activity which is extended from `ListActivity` I can detect `ListView` click 
just doing this:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Do something
}
```

Why it is so complex to do the same for long click detection?

Comment: `getListView().setOnLongClickListener(this);` in `onCreate` and let `ListActivity` implementing `AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener` is not complex ...

Comment: @Selvin, he/she would want to do getListView().setOnItemLongClickListener(this)

Comment: I agree with the author, anything in Android is complex and a bit of mess unfortunalty... And non of the suggestions works.